# How can I insert a blank un-formatted line in code block in Markdown?

Tags: markdown

Sometimes I want to contrast two separate pieces of code in a Stackoverflow post without putting spaces between them. However, Stackoverflow places consecutive code blocks all in the same block, regardless of spaces between them.

```
// first code block

// second code block
```

I want them to appear in separate code blocks, somewhat like this.

```
// first code block
```

`// second code block`

You'll notice that My first block is indented, whereas the second is surrounded by back tics, which is not ideal, as the second block won't be highlighted by Stackoverflow.

```
    // first code block

`// second code block`
```

How can I make both blocks appear as separate formatted code blocks using only indentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just solved it, thanks to a comment (which has since been deleted).

To force separate code blocks, place a `<blank>` tag between the code blocks.

```
// first code block
```

```
// second code block
```

as produced with this formatting.

```
    // first code block
<blank>

    // second code block
```

Comment: Nice catch.  By the way, your question belongs on the Meta site, not here.

Comment: I was going to put it on meta, but I thought it was more a markdown question than stackoverflow. I'll move it if your comment gets upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this invisible char: `⁣⁣` (http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2063/index.htm)

Example:

```
sdf
```

⁣

```
sdf
```

EDIT: The solution with `<blank>` makes more sense (also looks better, as the invisible char version's gap is a bit big)